# webjob and a virtual machine communication in azure

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have an Azure **Webjob** that has been deployed in an Azure **website**, I also got virtual machine that is hosting a **MongoDB** database on port 27017 which can be accessed for all the virtual machines under the same **cloud service**.

I need that Webjob to have access to that virtual machine service using an internal IP, It is possible to add this azure website / Webjob to the cloud service?

any other suggestions are more than welcome!
thanks!

Comment: You can't add a webjob to a cloud service.  I think a virtual network would get you what you're looking for.

Comment: if you have in mind any documentation that could be useful, I'll be more than glad to look on that direction! thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/

Comment: seems like this article is the one I was looking for http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/ thanks for sharing